# Разбор APK-Debug

Tags: java, android, apk

Прошу прощения, если вопросы данного характера нельзя задавать в рамках форума, отпишите в комментариях, я удалю.
Ситуация следующая:
Сделал готовый проект, заказчик оказался ... плохим человеком, начал гнуть свою линию.

1. Могут ли apk-debug разобрать и опубликовать в play market?
2. Каким образом я могу зарегестрировать авторские права на приложения?
   Может кто сталкивался с данными вопросами.

Comment: Я так понимаю ваш apk файл не был подписан?

Comment: К сожалению не был

Comment: Для вас к счастью. Они не смогут опубликовать не подписанный apk файл.

Comment: Также если ваш код обфусифицирован, то это затруднит разборку кода

Comment: Благодарю вас )